# Why does it work well in VisualStudioCode but not ubuntu 18.04 ? <The segmentation fault>

Tags: c

```
Bae:01000000000:Busy
Baek:01000000000:0222875074
Jung:022000000:Goodman
Kim:0102000000:
Han:010300000:ddd
```

///This is some data

```
#define MAX_LIST 1000
#define MAX_LINE 100

typedef struct
{
    char name[20];
    char phone[30];
    char memo[40];
} Tel;

Tel arr[MAX_LIST];
static int count = 0;
```

///This is structure

```
    void showList()
{
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        Tel element;
        fgets(line, MAX_LINE, fp);
        char *ptr = strtok(line, ":"); token --> ' : ' 
        strcpy(element.name, ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ":");
        strcpy(element.phone, ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        if (ptr == NULL)  //When the next part is empty
        {  
            ptr = " ";
        }
        strcpy(element.memo, ptr);
        arr[count++] = element;
    }  **//Everything is saved in the arr[], but a segmentation fault occurs after that.**
    fclose(fp);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("%d : %s %s %s\n", i, arr[i].name, arr[i].phone, arr[i].memo);
    }
}
```

> segmentation fault(core dumped)

///and I want to know, why segmentation fault occur after while loop  in ubuntu 18.04

I want to move on to the next.

Comment: `while (!feof(fp))` FAIL

Comment: Do basic error checking - check the return value of `strtok` and `fopen` before using their results. Check the string length before copying a potentially 100 character string into a 20 character buffer. Do basic debugging - run the program in the debugger and examine the variable values when it seg faults.

Comment: you can move on to the next if you have learned something here

Answer (score -1):

It works as different compilers run differently. Therefore while there might be memory leakage for a certain piece of code, your compiler on vscode might be ignoring it. However, that might not be the case on Ubuntu. You can use Valgrind to find where this memory leak is taking place and sort this issue out. Also, I would like to mention that if some compiler is showing a memory leak it mostly means that there is a memory leak and the best practice is to find it out even if you will be working on vscode most of the time. This is because if you don't solve this out, down the road when your program develops it will start acting weirdly. Find out more about valgrinf here.

Learn more about Valgrind [here](https://valgrind.org/).

Comment: More likely: a compiler allocated a bit more memory than asked, so some out-of-bounds writing is handled by this. Or: a compiler initiailzed malloced memory to zero.

Comment: A compiler cannot ignore memory leakage: it occurs in run-time, not compile-time.

Comment: Yes Paul might be right, I was meaning to say that. But compilers react differently to memory leaks is what I'm trying to say.